# How to make natbib cite title for references without an author

Tags: natbib

I'm using revtex4-1 and need to have parenthetical references. I have some references though with no author (like [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/permission.html), as well as a few other websites.) How do I force natbib to use the first few words of the title instead? So instead of `(noa n.d.)` I want something like `(Project Gutenberg, n.d.)`.

Comment: Please show a minimal working example with bibliography, that can be used to reproduce the problem and to test suggestions.

Comment: Use the `revtex4-2` class.  At the very least we need to see a full bib entry for this to be answerable, edit your question to give more information and it can be reopened.